# Checking for SELECT ALL (multi value parameter) in REPORT DATA Query

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, multivalue

In the Report Data Query I need to check whether SELECT ALL has been selected in a multivalue parameter. If it has I want to include records where the value for the related field is empty, otherwise I only want to select where the value is in @parameter. I have search EXTENSIVELY but none of the answers I have found e.g
- checking @parameter!field.count = Dataset.count    works within the REPORT DATA Query. I have used this info to display the list of selected values or "ALL" in the heading of the report.
I can't believe that others have not needed this functionality?

Comment: How about make the records where the related field is empty an option of "unknown". So if everything is selected.. even the Unknown is selected and will show the relevant records .. You just need to adjust your coding accordingly..

Comment: hmmnn thats an option Thanks Harry

Comment: If this works for you.. (it should) I'll put that down as an answer and can you please accept that.

Comment: It wouldn't let me post an answer with my resolution here is my solution - thanks Harry. SELECT 2 as sortit, employeeid, fullname from Employees union SELECT 1 as sortit, * FROM (SELECT 0 AS employeeid, 'Unassigned' as Fullname) Unassigned

order by sortit,Fullname

and the check in the Report Query: AND (s.EmployeeId in (@EmployeeId) or 0 in (@EmployeeId) and s.EmployeeID is Null)

Answer (score 0):

How about make the records where the related field is empty an option of "unknown". So if everything is selected.. even the Unknown is selected and will show the relevant records .. You just need to adjust your coding accordingly..